# How to reliably memory constrain a postgres database

Tags: postgresql, memory-management

I run postgres 10.4 on a very small machine with strict memory constraints (e.g. 200MB) on Debian. System swap space must be disabled in my case but SSD Disk space is plenty available (e.g. > 500GB). I am using a waterfall approach to distribute all available memory to the different uses in postgres following this logic:

```
The available memory is 200MB
---
max_connections = 10
max_worker_processes = 2
shared_buffers = 50MB
work_mem = (200MB - shared_buffers) * 0.8 / max_connections
maintenance_work_mem = (200MB - shared_buffers) * 0.1 / max_worker_processes
temp_buffers = (200MB - shared_buffers) * 0.05

wal_buffers = (200MB - shared_buffers) * 0.05
temp_file_limit = -1 (i.e. unlimited)
effective_cache_size = 200MB / 2
```

It is crucial for me, that sessions or even the postmaster are never canceled due to memory restrictions to ensure stable operation of postgres. In low memory situations postgres should work with temp files instead of memory.

I still get out of memory errors in some situations. (e.g. when I have a large insert into a table.)

How do I need to set all parameters to guarantee that postgres will not try to get more memory than there is available.

Comment: I would set work_mem lower (on my Raspberry3(1GB ram)  it is 4M) and random_page_cost also lower for an SSD (Pi:1.1)Also: monitor the RSS of the running processes.(and substract (some of) it from your 200MB,too)

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to this official document for the in-depth study of the memory configuration of postgresql server - https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server

It has all the limits and properly suggested values for each memory param, these params can be set using the server configuration attributes like # of CPUs, RAM capacity etc.

Else, use this online tool to try out different configurations and make sure that the server doesn't require more memory than what is available to it - https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/#/

Comment: Yes there are several detailed accounts on how to tune your postgres system. The issue I have is concerned with the fuzzyness of the reccommendations. 

e.g. There is statement like "... effective_cache_size should be set to an estimate of how much memory is available for disk caching ...". Does that mean the query executer will try to acquire memory using this parameter and if that fails then the session is canceled? 
Or if I have an n times merge join I use n times work_mem in one session. How can I put a hard limit on memory in that situation?

Comment: There is nothing that says "Limit the memory usage past this threshold". So, it's your task to create a configuration which is well within the memory you have. n time merge join should ideally be avoided, because postgresql is good at executing multiple lean queries concurrently (because each query will fit within work_mem). Tuning RDBMS is really tricky, you need to monitor your usage a lot and then tweak the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I guess I'm left to "tune and try". I wish there would be more direct info on memory usage effects of each setting in the docs, though.